# How to use JS to get multiple Giphy canvases to show up

Tags: javascript, giphy-api

https://codepen.io/amoslosky/pen/XWJjjML

```
var api="http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?";
//my API key//
var apiKey="api_key=MY_API_KEY&q=";
//rest of code linked above!//
```

I believe the error is in my js because I really don't understand js that well yet. On the left green panel, I want a 3x3 grid of Giphy gifs to show up. Each input box on the right green panel should control one row of 3 gifs.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I recommend not sharing an API key anywhere

Comment: I just hid your api key, don't share these publicly!

Comment: Thank you! I clearly have no idea what I'm doing!